# Add spaces to the start of lines in a blockquote

Tags: spacing, pdftex

I'm trying to typeset a poem in a `\blockquote`, but the spaces at the start of each line disappear when I make a PDF. How do I allow the spaces to remain at the beginning of each line of the poem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\blockquote{
\#6
\\
you\\
\\
\\
  are\\
\\
      inscribed\\
          in the\\
           lines on the\\
     ceiling\\
\\
      you\\
\\
 are\\
    \\
   inscribed in\\
         the depths\\
   of\\
         the\\
    storm\\
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple spaces are interpreted as *one* space by LaTeX. You could add the space you need with `\hspace*{}` commands.

```
\blockquote{
\#6
\\
you\\
\\
\\
\hspace*{1em}are\\
\\
\hspace*{3em}inscribed\\
\hspace*{5em}in the\\
\hspace*{6em}lines on the\\
\hspace*{2.5em}ceiling\\
\\
\hspace*{3em}you\\
\\
\hspace*{1em}are\\
\\
\hspace*{3em}inscribed in\\
\hspace*{4.5em}the depths\\
\hspace*{3em}of\\
\hspace*{4.5em}the\\
\hspace*{3.5em}storm\\
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer was lifted, almost verbatim, from Wynter Snow's excellent book [*TeX for the Beginner*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201547996):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\startline{\par\noindent}

{\obeylines\obeyspaces\gdef\beginPoem{%
    \begingroup%
    \obeylines\obeyspaces%
    \let^^M=\startline}%
\gdef\endPoem{\endgroup}

\begin{document}


\beginPoem
    \#6  
    \\
        you
    \\
    \\
        are\\
        \\
        inscribed\\
           in the\\
             lines on the\\
      ceiling\\
        \\
        you\\
    \\
            are\\
        \\
                 inscribed in\\
                       the depths\\
                   of\\
                               the\\
                       storm\\

                \endPoem           
\end{document}
```

Note that this is not compatible with the `csquotes` package.

Produces:

[image]

Another solution, one that is compatible with `csquotes` follows, and uses `\phantom` to visually produce spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\def\Sp{\noindent\phantom}

\begin{document}

\blockquote{
     \Sp{**********}Hello\\\
    \\
    \\
    \\
    \Sp{*******}Jello\\
    \Sp{*****************}Mello\\
Fellow}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]